# How to get a python String in a Template html?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I have a list of strings in python like this :

com = ['first first', 'second', 'bla bla bla']

I pass this list to an html template and I'd like to display in my html page only the second String ("second"), I try in this way :
{{ com.1 }}
but the result is "f". Why? How can I get the string "second" ?

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Could you show the complete code you have so far?

Comment: How do you pass `com` in your context data?

Comment: you could pass com[1] when you render using context variable

Answer (score 0):

Your technique used to call an object in an array by index (in the template) is correct, so the first step is to view how `com` renders in the template and make sure the variable is what you expect.

You can call an item in an array as you have.

In template, if `com = ['first first', 'second', 'bla bla bla']`:

```
{{ com }}
```

should render

```
['first first', 'second', 'bla bla bla']
```

In template -

```
{{ com.1 }}
```

renders

```
second
```

In template -

```
{% for each in com %}
    {% if forloop.counter0 == 1 %}
        {{ each }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

renders

```
second
```

Since your template technique appears to be correct, verify that `com` itself is of type `list` using (`print(type(com))` or `assert isinstance(com,list)` prior to assignment in template content).

Comment: `com.1` shows that the op isn't passing the array through correctly, so their technique isn't correct

Comment: I strictly meant the technique used in the template is correct; this is a valid way to call an object in an array by index in a Django template

Comment: Yes, but `com` isn't an array in the django template, it may be in the view but the problem lies in code that the op isn't showing us

Comment: I understand that; hence "if com = ['first first', 'second', 'bla bla bla']" and to investigate the type of object at time of assignment to the template context dictionary.

Comment: Sorry for my absence. Thank you for your answer, I verified the type of com and it's 'unicode'.
How can I convert it?

Comment: That means that whatever 'com' is in your context dictionary (passed to your template) is NOT actually a list/array but a unicode string. Python will parse strings by index  as if it were an ordered list of characters so that  string "Hello" at index [1] would be "e". 

In short, your view is not passing a list/array to your template.